# How to change the background color of a form in the mobile app?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

I want to change the background of form in the mobile application. Iam developing it using Netbeans 6.9 j2me. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lcdui form, then you can't. You can use [lwuit](http://lwuit.java.net/) is has so many features like this.